# How to call parent class init with default values from child class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-internals

I am trying to give my subclasses default variables and stop duplicating code as the file is getting fat:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, username=None, password=None, start_url=None):
        self.username  = username
        self.password  = password
        self.start_url = start_url

class Subclass(Base):

    def __init__(self, username="hoss_it87", password="whatsgoodSO", start_url="www.boss-sauce.com"):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__()
```

`Base` works of course, but I want `Subclass` to init the same way, just overriding the `None` with real strings (all login styles are similar of course).

```
In [12]: x = Base('myuser', 'mypassword', 'www.google.com')

In [13]: x.username
Out[13]: 'myuser'

In [14]: x.start_url
Out[14]: 'www.google.com'

In [15]: y = Subclass()

In [16]: y.username

In [17]: y.start_url

In [18]: y.password

In [19]:
```

Why do I get nothing for `Subclass` attributes, and how can I fix it? Thank you

Please note removing base class defaults causes other issues

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, username, password, start_url):
        self.username  = username
        self.password  = password
        self.start_url = start_url

class Subclass(Base):

    def __init__(self, username="honeybooboosbiggestfan", password="toomuchburkerking", start_url="www.imjokingiprefericeroadtruckers.com"):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__()


In [24]: y = Subclass()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-55b9b4fdf93b> in <module>()
----> 1 y = Subclass()

<ipython-input-23-a9dc62450db7> in __init__(self, username, password, start_url)
      9 
     10     def __init__(self, username="honeybooboosbiggestfan", password="toomuchburkerking", start_url="www.imjokingiprefericeroadtruckers.com"):
---> 11         super(Subclass, self).__init__()

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)

In [25]:
```

Solved:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, username, password, start_url):
        self.username  = username
        self.password  = password
        self.start_url = start_url

class Subclass(Base):

    def __init__(self, username="honeybooboosbiggestfan", password="toomuchburkerking", start_url="www.imjokingiprefericeroadtruckers.com"):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__(username=username, password=password, start_url=start_url)

## -- End pasted text --

In [26]: y = Subclass()

In [27]: y.username
Out[27]: 'honeybooboosbiggestfan'

In [28]:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the arguments from the `SubClass` init to the init block of `Base`:

```
class Subclass(Base):

    def __init__(self, username="hoss_it87", password="whatsgoodSO", start_url="www.boss-sauce.com"):
        super(Subclass, self).__init__(username=username, password=password, start_url=start_url)
```

In your code, the `Base` init is called without arguments and thus takes its default arguments, which are all `None`.

Comment: I see, it literally just calls `Base.__init__`. That actually makes sense, lemme go try again

Comment: thank you, says I have to wait 7 minutes to accept for some reason

Comment: worked very well, with the attribute = value pairs passed to super class.